# Escaping Symbol in json array using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm passing some data through Json array to an html table. My problem is that the encoding of some frensh letter like (é, è, à),

my json array is like :

```
paniersFromJsonFile = [
{ 
"reference": "62010",
"LibelleDeLaPiece": "BOUCLIER",
"origine": "Pièce d'origine",
"distributeur": "datasier"
},
{ 
"reference": "60100",
"LibelleDeLaPiece": "Grille",
"origine": "Pièce d'origine",
"distributeur": "mvc"
}]
```

in the screen i have this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can use utf-8 encoding.that should solve the problem

Comment: thank you for your answer, in my eclipse all my editor is in utf8, but it dont work

Comment: specify the type in your class Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: can your explain me more, where i must put this line of content-type

Answer (score 0):

yes,you need to save file as UTF-8(As gautam said) without BOM (Byte Order Mark in the begining of the file), Notepad++ allows that option

Comment: i have the same problem, i have copied the array in notepaad++, and i have changed the encoding to the utf without BOM, it dont work

Comment: yes, we have juste one difference, my array is in js variable, not angular variable

Comment: i note that i use an ngDialog to display data in html table

Comment: maybe that is converting your format for displaying try removing it and check

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: i use an application server